# Mehrteiliges Subjekt und nur gemeinsames Hilfsverb - Singular oder Plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

Bei mehrteiliegen Subjekten ist es ja (meistens) besser, das Verb im Plural zu verwenden:

> Hans und Maria wurden gelobt. Hast du gehört, dass Hans und Maria gelobt wurden?

Sehe ich es rightig, dass aber Singular einzig richtig ist, wenn es sich gar nicht um ein mehrteiliges Subjet mit gemeinsamem Prädikat handelt, sondern nur ein Hilfswerb geteilt wird? (Weil wir es genaug genommen gar nicht mit einem mehrteiliges Subjekt zu tun haben sondern einer Ellipse)

> Hast du gehört, dass Hans gelobt, Maria gerügt und Peter getadelt wurde[n]?

Answer (score 1):

Selbstverständlich mus hier das geteilte Hilfsverb im Singular stehen, da ja immer nur eine Person betroffen ist.

Sollte allerdings mindestens eins der Subjekte im Plural stehen,

> Hast du gehört, dass Hans und seine Frau gelobt, Maria gerügt und Peter getadelt wurde?

> Hast du gehört, dass Maria gerügt, Peter getadelt und Hans und seine Frau gelobt wurden?

steht üblicherweise das Verb im Numerus des im am nächsten stehenden Subjekts.